# I need permission from myself to delete folders w/Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to delete some folders on my C: drive, but I cannot remove them after we got switched over to using AD and Group policy on our domain.  When I try to delete the folder it tells me "You require permission from OURDOMAIN\matt.johnson to make changes to this folder", but then if I open up powershell and run `whoami` it tells my I am 'OURDOMAIN\matt.johnson'... so why do I still not have permission to delete it! I even tried using `takeown` then `rmdir` and I still get permission denied errors.

Comment: Are you running your Powershell console as administrator?  What do the NTFS permissions look like?

Answer (score 0):

Well, not exactly a PowerShell issue but more about user rights elevation in the post-XP OSes.
Right click on PowerShell Icon, and choose "runas Administrator", then run your command.